# keep python script running wile also waiting for a tcp connection

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

Is their a way of making a python script keep looping running even wile it is waiting for a TCP connection or a message coming in via TCP.

I have produced a "Program" that i would like to run as a stand alone but also be able to control it via a TCP connection. I have the main part of the program running as i would like it but when adding the TCP Control to it my python script pauses at either the part where its waiting for a TCP Connection or a message to come into the script via TCP. is there a way around this?

```
s.listen(0)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print('connected by', addr)

#-------------------------LOOP START----------------------------------------
while continue_reading:
    print 'HELP 1'

    doc = minidom.parse(folder + file)
    card = doc.getElementsByTagName("card")

#------------IP Stuff---------------
    data = conn.recv(1024)

    if data:
        print 'Help 2'
        if data == "THEME?":
           itemlist = doc.getElementsByTagName('card')
           conn.send(str(len(itemlist))+"\r\n")

           for x in itemlist:
               xcard = x.attributes['id'].value
               xname = x.getElementsByTagName("name")[0]
               xfname = xname.firstChild.data
               conn.send(xcard+" - "+xfname+"\r\n")

        elif data == "RUNNING?":
           print"RUNNING?"
           conn.send(uid2 +" - "+fname+ "\r\n")

#----------------Rest of program runs below this line working fine-----------
```

Comment: Use `select`, `epoll`, or threads. There are "event loop" libraries that make this easier, like GLib, Twisted, etc.

Comment: thanks @JonathonReinhart i kinda understand the select within python but still new to this. I am working on a RPi. so in your eyes what would be the best solution for me. Any links to the libraries and examples would be great.